# Pressing Shift+a in 1 of my joomla sites = select all?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, editor, shift

A client of ours is having a problem - Every time she presses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (to get capital letter `A`), it selects all the stuff in the article, as if you were to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. It doesn't do this on their other Joomla! sites. I replicated the problem on my computer, so it's not just a faulty keyboard.

Could this be a php issue somewhere? Has anyone else had this happen to them? It's in Joomla! 2.5.5 so it's the most updated version too.

This issue is annoying the client, as they end up selecting everything, and keep typing, which deletes everything. Apart from my remark of "just press caps lock and then press it again when you're done", we're not sure what to do.

This also only happens in Chrome, not Firefox, though we don't really want her leaving Chrome.

Comment: can you link us the client's site so we can inspect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was an [embarrassing bug](http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/news/item/jce-2212-released) in Joomla Content Editor, which was fixed in JCE 2.2.1.2 on June 29

```
This update fixes a bug introduced in TinyMCE 3.5.4 where SHIFT + A in Chrome would select all content instead of creating an uppercase A.
```

Updating JCE will hopefully get rid of this annoying behavior.

Comment: Thanks ampersandre! That's totally the answer! Fixed :)